# Jmeter Maven 2.1.0- Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

This question was attempted to be answered here in this post:
[Jmeter- Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467401/jmeter-error-in-nonguidriver-java-lang-illegalargumentexception)
but the solution didn't work, was wondering if anyone else had another solution or can clarify the solution...

I'm trying to run Jmeter Maven plugin (version 2.1.0) to run my Jmeter script which was written in version 3.1 of Jmeter. I followed all of the instructions mentioned here https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin to create the pom.xml file.

when i execute the following maven command:

```
mvn clean verify -Denv=prod -Djmx.filename={the_name_of_my_jmx_file}
```

i get the following 2 errors:

## 1

```
[INFO] Invalid value detected for <postTestPauseInSeconds>.  Setting pause to 0...
```

## 2

```
[INFO] Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from: {path to my jmx file} missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
    [INFO] ---- Debugging information ----
    [INFO] cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    [INFO] cause-message       : 
    [INFO] first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    [INFO] class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
    [INFO] required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    [INFO] converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
    [INFO] path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[2]/kg.apc.jmeter.reporters.LoadosophiaUploader
    [INFO] line number         : 2051
    [INFO] version             : 3.1 r1770033
```

the pom.xml file i'm using is here:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.company.testframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project-performance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Performance test script for project</name>

    <properties>
        <jmeter.version>3.1</jmeter.version>
        <jmeter.maven.plugin>2.1.0</jmeter.maven.plugin>
        <!-- <jmeter.maven.plugin>1.10.1</jmeter.maven.plugin> -->
        <jmeter.plugins.standard>1.1.3</jmeter.plugins.standard>
        <jmeter.plugins.extras>1.3.1</jmeter.plugins.extras>
        <!-- <jmeter.plugins.extras>1.4.0</jmeter.plugins.extras> -->
        <env>prod</env>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>src/test/resources/conf/${env}.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jmeter.maven.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterVersion>${jmeter.version}</jmeterVersion>
                    <resultsFileFormat>xml</resultsFileFormat>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>
                    <ignoreResultFailures>false</ignoreResultFailures>
                    <overrideRootLogLevel>INFO</overrideRootLogLevel>
                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:pom:1.3.1</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <environment>${env}</environment>
                        <jtl_file_name>${jmx.filename}.jtl</jtl_file_name>
                        <project_build_directory>${project.build.directory}</project_build_directory>
                        <!-- Project Specific Properties -->
                        <main_threads>${main.threads}</main_threads>
                        <rampup_seconds>${rampup.seconds}</rampup_seconds>
                        <duration_seconds>${duration.seconds}</duration_seconds>
                        <host_url>${host.url}</host_url>
                        <user_name>${user.name}</user_name>
                        <user_password>${user.password}</user_password>
                        <offer_id>${offer.id}</offer_id>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <propertiesJMeter>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>csv</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.url>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.url>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format>ms</jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format>yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format>
                        <httpclient4.retrycount>3</httpclient4.retrycount>
                        <httpsampler.await_termination_timeout>60</httpsampler.await_termination_timeout>
                        <http.socket.timeout>20000</http.socket.timeout>
                    </propertiesJMeter>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${jmx.filename}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-standard</artifactId>
                        <version>${jmeter.plugins.standard}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
                        <version>${jmeter.plugins.extras}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding%20Additional%20Libraries%20To%20The%20Classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory)

> You can add any additional Java libraries to JMeter's lib/ext directory by using the  configuration element. This uses the Eclipse Aether libraries to perform dependency resolution.

So it should be enough to do the following:

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:pom:1.3.1</artifact>
    </jmeterExtensions>
</configuration>
```

Your manual dependency adding via `dependencies` section is not required, moreover you specified version `1.1.3` in `dependencies` and version `1.3.1` in `jmeterExtensions`

Finally, your uploader won't work as it has been superseded with the [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) Uploader therefore I would recommend switching to plugin version 1.4.0.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! when you recommend using plugin version 1.4.0 are you referring to the jmeter maven plugin, or the jmeter-plugins-standard?

Comment: I'm talking about [jmeter-plugins-standard](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-standard/1.4.0). In regards to JMeter Maven plugin, you should be using [jmeter-maven-plugin-1.10.1](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/releases) unless you are suffering from a bug which is fixed in later pre-releases